# Eth locked in contract, I have been scammed?

Tags: solidity, ether, scam

Following a blog, I created a contract using this code:
https://pastebin.com/WAaLCGxW
Now, I don't know what I did, but all the ETH I sent to the contract ended up through "internal transactions" in another address from which I can't retrieve them.
The address where they ended up is this:

0x78Ba3Cd47408E6C82a29d6AD9961a40e0E62a38d.

Can someone help me?

Comment: This question has been asked so many times just this week. Please use the search bar before posting a new question.

Comment: Sometimes, I think the scammers are here asking the question.